# Sequelize bulk update with inner join

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am currently working with Sequelize and can not figure out how to update bulk when im associating two tables together. I have the follow:

Tables:

```
members
   user_id
   channel_id
   all

activities
   user_id
   channel_id
```

I am trying to update `members.all` when the user_ids match, `members.channel_id` is 2 and `activities.channel_id` is not 2.

Here is working Postgresql:

```
UPDATE members AS m 
   SET    "all" = true 
   FROM   activities AS a 
   WHERE  m.user_id = a.user_id 
      AND m.channel_id = 2 
      AND a.current_channel != 2;
```

Is this possible to do is sequelize? How do include `a.current_channel != 2` into my current update?

```
Member.update(
        { all: true },
        { where: { channel_id: channelId } },
)
```

When I try to add an include it does not work.

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't do something like that using Sequelize `update` method. I would use the include option in a `findAll` method, but as far as I can see on the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update), there is no include option for the `update` method.

You could use a raw query to use directly the query.

```
sequelize.query("UPDATE members AS m SET "all" = true FROM activities AS a WHERE m.user_id = a.user_id AND m.channel_id = 2 AND a.current_channel != 2").spread((results, metadata) => {
  // Results will be an empty array and metadata will contain the number of affected rows.
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That is currently how I have it but was wondering if there was a way with sequelize and I missed it in the docs. Guess not

Answer (score 0):

Generally, i use this hack

```
models.findAll({
 where: {
 // which models to update
 }
}).then(targets => {
 models.target.update({
 // your updates
},{
 where : {
  target_primary_key: targets.map(t => t.primary_key)
 }
})

})
```

Comment: you can optimize this further by adding the attributes option and only select the primary key attribute in query 1.

Comment: Does this scale well? Would the bulk update be better in that aspect?

Comment: @user081608 its not infinitely scalable, the primary keys array is loaded into memory.

Comment: this is not bulk update. Question is about bulk update.